# The Biggest Chess Blunder

Tags: optimization, chess

Everyone knows that sinking feeling when you blunder your queen in one move, but it could be worse.

[image: a primitive example]

In the position above, Black plays Nf7. This blunders a knight in one move, as well as a bishop-king fork. In total, Black blundered 6 points of material in one move.

**How much material can be blundered in this manner in one move?**

Restrictions:

1. The attacking side must capture on every turn.
2. Every move must be forced (except the first blunder, of course).
3. Your final score is (enemy material taken) - (your material loss).

Comment: Are you aware of an optimal solution to this?

Comment: @bobble No, I'm not. Was that a requirement? I've seen a few puzzles of this nature before (ie. with strict restrictions but no known optimal answer).

Comment: It's not strictly required, especially for [chess] since there's a chess-loving lobby hereabouts :) but if you knew one it would help. The idea is to prevent [open-ended] puzzles where the whole thing turns into an never-ending game of answers upon answers one-upping each other

Comment: The biggest blunder — with the largest material loss — is, of course, to decline the Chess match in favour of [Global Thermonuclear War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WarGames)…

Comment: Are you interested in legal positions only? Given the new, albeit wrong, answer uses an illegal position, you could in theory produce far bigger a score.

Comment: @RewanDemontay Not gonna lie, I don't know a whole lot about chess. I just saw a situation like the one I put in the question in a video, and thought it would be fun to take it to the extreme. If you've got ideas for scoring higher with an illegal position, go ahead and try

Comment: Two more questions: By "every move must be forced," I assume you mean only the "defending" side must have only one legal move each turn, and must the sequence end in checkmate? I assume both from the accepted answer, but it is not quite clear.

Comment: @RewanDemontay I don't consider either a strict requirement. As long as the defending side is playing their best move. I think this kind of puzzle will almost certainly result in mate as well

Comment: Since my words are being twisted to claim otherwise: **optimization puzzles must have provably optimal solutions**. The only reason pre-knowledge is not strictly necessary for being on-topic is that if I try to close-vote based on it (and believe me, I want to close-vote this), hordes of chess lovers descend to defend the puzzle and cry that it's not needed for every asker to know the solution upon posting. Technically, knowledge of a solution is sufficient but unnecessary, but there's an extremely strong correlation between not knowing a solution and having no optimum practically provable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Score 156.

> [image]

*Thanks to @thisIs4d for helpful discussion.*

Black could win by 1... Bg6-c2#

If instead they make the blunder 1... Ne3-g4 white can force the line

[Variant "From Position"]
[FEN "Rrrqqqqq/PPPPPPP1/kq1qqqbb/7R/K7/4n3/8/8 b - - 1 1"]

1... Ng4 (1... Bc2#) 2. axb8=Q+ Qa7 3. Rxa7+ Kb6 4. bxc8=Q+ Kc6 5. cxd8=Q+ Qc7 6. Rxc7+ Kd6 7. dxe8=Q+ Qd7+ 8. Rxd7+ Ke6 9. exf8=Q+ Qe7 10. Rxe7+ Kf6 11. fxg8=Q+ Bf7 12. Rxf7+ Kg6 13. Qxg4+ Bg5 14. Rxg5+ Kh6 15. gxh8=Q#

Black's material at the start is 100, and is 0 at the end, netting us 100 points from that. White's material is worth 17 at the beginning, but 73 at the end; 17-73 = -56. By applying the same formula to both sides, you can take advantage of the scoring system's equation setup. Therefore, per restriction #3, our score is 100-(-56) = 156.

(click [here](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1177/7297) to replay the moves on Chess Stack Exchange)

Comment: I wonder why you didn't consider 8 queens instead in the first case above, wouldn't that increase the score to 136 (stalemate & checkmate can be avoided considering black king to blunder again)? Also, its good that both are possible situations in a chess game.

Comment: What's the move sequence in the "black could easily win with 1. ... Qh8xh7+" variation? Looks like the white king starts to run out of squares really fast.

Comment: @thisIs4d I don't know how to do it while keeping black's moves forced.

Comment: @bass I didn't work out the exact sequence as it seems obvious that black can just activate as many of their queens as needed checking the white king in every move.

Comment: @loopywalt, can you consider following changes in the first solution above: 

1. White queen on a8.

2. White rook on a6.
3. Black queen on a5.
Rest is the same as shown above.

Now if 1...Qa1, 2 Rxa1, you get your original solution with a +4 score, i.e. 123

Comment: @loopywalt In the new variant, you can add a black Knight at b3, to get +3, making the score 150

Comment: @thisIs4d I'm pretty sure that would make it an unreachable position because to get all the white pawns past all the black pawns 8 pieces must already have been captured and there are already 24 pieces on the board.

Comment: @loopywalt oh yes you are right. still there's one more piece which can probably be replaced somehow. i.e. white pawn on h6, which is only used to block the checks, instead we could have used a black knight / black bishop, but have to figure out some other configuration to make it forced for black

Comment: @thisIs4d Actually, you can just replace the white pawn h6 with a white knight. It not being a pawn alone frees up one piece, so you can add that black knight on b3.

Comment: @loopywalt yes, having 7 white passed-pawns ensures 6 captured pieces, and since we would have 25 pieces, that would do. So this adds +3 making it 150

Comment: @loopywalt clever solution! are you sure the remaining black knight won't fit? because 7 passed pawns can allow 26 pieces, black pieces being 16 in total (i.e. with no black capture)...   If its possible, then we can move both the black bishops to b1 and c1, and place second black knight on g5, increasing the score by +3 making it 159. 159 is anyways a theoretical upper bound, which in case would be strict.

Comment: @thisIs4d Where does this 26 come from? Each of the 7 white pawns had a black pawn in front of them. IIRC to create a passed pawn you have to (1) remove the opposing black pawn by (a) capturing it or (b) it capturing something or (2) sidestep it which requires the white pawn to capture something. 1a and 2 combined can create two white passed pawns with a single capture (so you could have 8 white passed pawns with 28 pieces still on the board) but if you want to retain or promote all black pawns option 1a is not available and if you want to retain all black pieces then only option 1b remains.

Answer (score 1):

For fun and an illegal position, using @loopy walt's matrix, here is a score of 206; (149)-(17-74).

> [image]

FEN: Rqqqqqqq/PPPPPPP1/kq1qqqq1/7R/K2p2q1/4qp2/6r1/1q2b1Rq b - - 1 1

Black blunders 1... Rf2, followed by 2. axb8=Q+ Qa7 3. Rxa7+ Kb6 4. bxc8=Q+ Kc6 5. cxd8=Q+ Qc7 6. Rxc7+ Kd6 7. dxe8=Q+ Qd7+ 8. Rxd7+ Ke6 9. exf8=R+ Qe7 10. Rxe7+ Kf6 11. fxg8=Q+ Qf7 12. Rexf7+ Kg6 13. Qxg4+ Qg5 14. Rxg5+ Kh6 15. Rxh1+ Rh2 16. Rxh2+ Bh4 17. gxh8=Q+ Qh7 18. Rxh7#

Answer (score 0):

Score 177.

> [image]

Notice Black only has three available moves. After the blunder Qbc2 and bxa8=Q Black is in zugzwang and must sacrifice each of the remaining Queens. Then after the Black King takes back the Bishop, White can easily clean up all of the Black Rooks with the newly promoted Queens.

[Variant "From Position"]
[FEN "qbrbrbrb/bPbPbPbP/rbrbrbrb/brbrbrbr/Kbrbrbrb/brbrbrbk/Bb1bqbqb/bqbqbqbq b - - 0 1"]

1... Qbc2 2. bxa8=Q Qb1 3. Bxb1 Qc2 4. Bxc2 Qd1 5. Bxd1 Qe2 6. Bxe2 Qf1 7. Bxf1+ Qg2 8. Bxg2+ Kxg2 9. dxc8=Q Kh3 10. fxe8=Q Kg2 11. hxg8=Q Kf1 12. Qxg6 Kg2 13. Qxh5 Kh3 14. Qcxe6 Kg2 15. Qxf5 Kh3 16. Qhxg4+ Kg2 17. Qxc6 Kh1 18. Qxb5 Kg2 19. Qxe4 Kh1 20. Qxa6 Kg2 21. Qxc4 Kf1 22. Qgxd5 Ke2 23. Kxb3 Kf1 24. Qcxd3+ Kg2 25. Qexf3#

Captured material 148, own losses 3 from the Bishop and -32 from promotion. Score 148-(3-32) = 177.

Comment: I'd say there is no blunder on Black's part because there is no way they can win, so there is nothing being lost here.

Comment: Nor are all of Black's moves forced, since the Black king has lots of freedom.