# A balanced banquet

Tags: optimization, chess, construction

As your king's fitness adviser you have been tasked with optimising His Majesty's diet. This entails making sure that the king eats equal amounts of carbs (rooks), fat (bishops) and protein (knights). As the king enjoys his meals you better have enough of each on the table.

> Task: Place a white king and **equal numbers** of black rooks, bishops and knights on a chess board such that the following becomes possible:
>
> 1. Only white moves.
> 2. White must capture a black piece with every move.
> 3. White must capture all black pieces.
> 4. White must never be in check except possibly before their first move.
>
> The goal is placing as many black pieces as possible subject to the stated rules.

Comment: We've seen several puzzles recently with a goal (roughly) of "find the best/most ...". As a reminder, this community decided to [do away with open-ended puzzles](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6617/30633). For an actual [tag:optimization] problem, rather than a "best score wins" game, "[answers should come with justification of why they are optimal; an answer without this is not a full answer](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6619)." If an answer cannot meaningfully be expected to show reasoning as to why it is indeed THE best answer, the question is likely improper.

Comment: I was led to believe that these are not rigorously enforced rules, especially in chess (see for example comments by not-exactly-firebrand bobble here: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/120364/73836). If the optimization tag is what bothers you I'll be happy to lose it. Besides, an optimal solution trivially exists and proving optimality may be difficult but is certainly feasible (I do not understand the meaning of "meaningfully expect").

Comment: I read bobble's comment to mean it's ok if the asker doesn't know of an optimal answer, but is asking because they strongly suspect one to exist. Puzzles generally are designed to have a single correct *solution* which is recognizable as such. Open-ended questions conversely feel like a game where the object is to find an answer that beats the other answers in some score or metric, but there is no definitive *solution* that is provably THE best possible answer; the accepted answer is just "the best someone has come up with so far". The former is ok, the latter is not, tags notwithstanding.

Comment: @loopywalt having fiddled with pencil and paper for quite some time in search of 6 of each, is there a trivially optimal solution using all 64 squares (21 of each dish)?

Comment: @WeatherVane are you asking me to spoiler it already? I don't think I can. Maybe in a week or so.

Comment: @WeatherVane No, there cannot be 64 filled squares. Observe that if in $i^{th}$ move the white king captures piece $P_i$ and in $j^{th}$ move ($j>i$) king captures piece $P_j$, then initially, $P_j$ MUST not attack $P_i$, else $P_i$ cannot be captured by king in the first place since it was supported by $P_j$. If there were 64 filled squares, then $P_{63}$ will always "support" some earlier captured piece. So, this is not possible. Moreover, its not quite hard to see that there can be maximum 22 pieces initially. I believe this can be reduced to 16, but I don't have time now. Good Luck :)

Comment: C'mon, @Rubio, just take a step back and compare your interpretation with what she has actually written. They don't really match, do they? Anyway, as I said I do not only suspect there is an optimal solution, I know it for a fact. So I take it that is settled, then.

Comment: @Rubio As the asker of the linked question, I think the same rule should be applied to this puzzle and mine (regardless of what the choice is). Both puzzles fall into a grey area that doesn't fit either of the characteristics you've described. To elaborate, an optimal answer must exist, as the chessboard is finite and can only fit so much material. However, this answer is very difficult to find, to the point where the puzzle may devolve into an open-ended competition.

Comment: @ApexPolenta I think there's no question the rule should be applied to both; that's ideally how rules work. I'm not saying either one should be closed, I was (as I said) just giving a reminder that optimization puzzles need to actually *be optimizable* to [prevent open-ended puzzles where the whole thing turns into an never-ending game of answers upon answers one-upping each other](/q/120364#comment335903_120364) — *exactly* "what [bobble] has actually written" and largely what I wrote too, insinuations to the contrary notwithstanding. If (as we're assured) THIS one is optimizable, all's well.

Comment: @ApexPolenta As for your puzzle, I have the same concerns I had upon first impressions when seeing this one. Technically, any chess puzzle _must_ have some optimal solution, but chess is a far cry from (say) a fully solved game like tic-tac-toe; it may well be that "an answer cannot meaningfully be expected to show reasoning as to why it is indeed THE best answer" due to the complexity of the game and the difficulty in finding and proving optimality of a specific solution. But if such solutions are not available, the only thing left may be the game-ish one-upping the rule seeks to avoid. Alas.

Comment: @Rubio You are misquoting by omission, conveniently leaving out "It's not strictly required, especially for [chess] since there's a chess-loving lobby hereabouts :) but [...] it would help. The idea is to [...]".

Comment: @loopywalt bobble didn't ask "Is there an optimal solution?" bobble asked "Are you aware of an optimal solution to this?"  You seem to be reading the "It" in "It's not strictly required" to be "A demonstrably optimal solution". I am reading it, as I noted previously, as "You knowing an optimal solution", as even if the OP doesn't know one but has good reason to think one exists, the chess-loving folks will probably find it if it can be found, so while OP knowing an optimal solution exists "would help", it may be fine—provided (as she goes on to explain) that things don't devolve to a game.

Comment: @loopywalt I'm not sure why you seem to take such offense at my comments, or appear to assume bad faith on my part. The rule is what it is. It doesn't carve out exceptions for chess puzzles. Even if bobble thinks it should (which I, at least, don't think her comment meant), bobble's opinion isn't the deciding factor anyway. Between the policy meta post I cited up front, everything I and others added to the discussion there, and my comments here, I've now said all I'm going to. This isn't an attack on you; it was—and is—a cautionary note. If it doesn't apply to you, then it doesn't. 'Nuff said.

Comment: @Rubio yeah, let's leave it at that.

Comment: "It" in that comment meant "knowledge of the optimal solution", not "existence of an optimal solution". The latter is always required. Honestly, I would have close-voted the other, but I was loathe to get drawn into an extended argument where I got accused of fun-killing.

Comment: @bobble Let me apologise for drawing you into this in the first place, it must be awkward having one's words pored over like this. That said please note that I did not make any claims re the meaning of "it" in this context. Suggesting otherwise is the kind of misdirection I find annoying. I decided not to contest it this time because I, too, don't enjoy protracted and ultimately pointless arguments.

Comment: So, is the given 7 pieces the best solution you know or are there better? I managed more pieces on the board where teleporting king would gobble them all, but there was no path to eat them all (eg 8 is trivial, from the 7 each solution add knights to d5 and f5, bishop to a3 and replace f3 with rook. There are other quasi-solutions with even more pieces, but I didn't find anything connected)

Comment: @ZizyArcher No, seven was the best I could find, too. thisIs4d says they have proof that seven is indeed the maximum, but they re too busy, apparently ;-)

Answer (score 10):

<strike>Six</strike> Seven each is the least a king should settle for:

> [image]

Former (19 piece) answer:

> [image]

Answer (score 7):

I begin this meal with an appetizer of 5 each.

> [image]